# Query-based editor for VCard files (Linux)

Tags: linux

I have a large personal address book (currently held in Google Contacts) that's synced to by various devices and programs, and it seems not one of them does things exactly the same. The end result is that every year or so I have to through and manually deduplicate, fix inconsistencies, and generally decruft everything. For instance, an import of contacts from a certain webservice some time ago resulted in a number of contacts having a birth year of '1' where they had marked it private in their profile.

What I'm looking for is a VCF editor that would allow me to operate on my address book with a query language, such that I could for instance find every contact with a birth year before 1900 and simply unset the field.

Answer (score 2):

Not very user friendly, but I edit such files using [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) (a plain text editor).

vim allows you to perform search/replace operations with regular expressions, which is useful for the kind of scenarios you describe.

I would be glad to hear about any more user-friendly solution.

Comment: I'm familiar with Vim and RegEx, which is my current approach. It works, but I was hoping for something records-based with smarter conditions. If I get bored, perhaps I'll bang out something in Python to do it myself, and I'll drop you a line if I do. Thanks, though.